# How to upload a file from a sheet (via VBA macro) to a laravel application?

Tags: excel, laravel, rest, web, laravel-4

I'm trying to make a spreedsheet "upload itself" to a RESTful web service made in Laravel 4.

I have a web form who does the same work, but I need to, instead of make the user go to the web application and manually upload the file, make the sheet capable of upload itself from a click of a button (using macros). I have a method that receives the `Input::file('filename')` and open the file to read and stuff. I'm using the `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` VBA object to send the request to the WS. Saddly, I ain't seem to be able to upload the god damm file! I'm sending the path (absolute path) in the post method, but isn't working.

The problem is: How I do this within a VBA code? How do I upload a file to the server through a VBA code? And, if it is possible, how to made that compatible with a laravel application?

EDIT

To proper answer to @Andreyco's question, I'm making this edit.

That's what I receive in the VBA Debug Tool when I return the dump of `Input::all()`

```
Array
(
    [spreedsheet] => C:\Users\Android\Desktop\tarifa.xls
)
```

...but, when I receive the response from the web form, it looks like this.

```
Array
(
    [_token] => rvtkLep6rwvkvvXc3u0WoO6nyldylp9xI36n6gb2
    [spreedsheet] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
    (
        [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
        [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => tarifa.xls
        [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => application/vnd.ms-excel
        [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 43520
        [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
        [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /tmp/phpRsX5bf
        [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpRsX5bf
    )
)
```

... because of Laravel structure and stuff. Hope it will be useful.

Comment: Are you able to inspect the response of POST request?

Comment: In the application, I change the code so I could see the return. I'm echoing the `Input::all()` to see what has been received, and I'm returning to the debug console of the VBA Macro Edit from Excel.  

`Array( [spreedsheet] => C:\Users\Android\Desktop\tarifa.xls)`

Comment: Don't know how about VBA, but in order to send file from HTML form, you need to allow it (use multipart form). Try to examine `Input::file()`, especialy `Input::has('keyToYourFile')` to see if file is sent. More here: http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files

Comment: @Andreyco Before return the `Input::all()`, I have a `$sheet = Input::file('filename')`. I already checked and the `$sheet` is empty, that means that the file isn't been seending...

Comment: Yeah, file is not sent then. Just to be sure, 'filename' is just a key in $_FILES global variable you can use to access file being uploaded (not the actual file name).

Comment: @Andreyco Yeah, I know that. In that case, I'm calling the input name. In the VBA code it is that way: `http.send "spreedsheet=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & ThisWorkbook.Name` , where "spreedsheet" is the name of the field in the web form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure it out in the follow 
[IT Blog](http://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/) and it served me "like a glove"! Just two simple VBA functions/methods that did the job so f**king well! I Just needed to pass the file and the URL and it was done!

Thanks @Andreyco for your help! ;)

Answer (score 5):

Here a complete, working example. If you do not need the "Please Wait" dialog just use the first code snippet and delete `UploadThisFileMain` thereof. Also note the server PHP test script at the very end.

```
Sub UploadThisFileMain()
   If ActiveWorkbook.Saved = False Then
       MsgBox "This workbook contains unsaved changes. Please save first."
       Exit Sub
   End If
   Dim ret
   ret = StartProcessing("File uploading, Please Wait...", "UploadThisFile")
   If (ret = True) Then
       MsgBox "Upload successful!"
    Else
       MsgBox "Upload failed: " & ret
   End If
End Sub

Private Function UploadThisFile()
    Dim bound As String
    bound = "A0AD2346-9849-4EF0-9A93-ACFE17910734"

    Dim url  As String
    url = "https://<YourServer>/index.php?id={" & bound & "}"

    Dim path As String
    path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

    sMultipart = pvGetFileAsMultipart(path, bound)

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim r
    r = pvPostMultipart(url, sMultipart, bound)

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      UploadThisFile = Err.Description
      Err.Clear
    Else
      UploadThisFile = True
    End If
End Function

'sends multipart/form-data To the URL using WinHttprequest/XMLHTTP
'FormData - binary (VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY) multipart form data
Private Function pvPostMultipart(url, FormData, Boundary)
  Dim http 'As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

  'Create XMLHTTP/ServerXMLHTTP/WinHttprequest object
  'You can use any of these three objects.
  'Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttprequest.5")
  'Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
  Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

  'Open URL As POST request
  http.Open "POST", url, False

  'Set Content-Type header
  http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + Boundary

  'Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
  http.send FormData

  'Get a result of the script which has received upload
  pvPostMultipart = http.responseText
End Function

Private Function pvGetFileAsMultipart(sFileName As String, Boundary As String) As Byte()
    Dim nFile           As Integer
    Dim sPostData       As String
    '--- read file
    nFile = FreeFile
    Open sFileName For Binary Access Read As nFile
    If LOF(nFile) > 0 Then
        ReDim baBuffer(0 To LOF(nFile) - 1) As Byte
        Get nFile, , baBuffer
        sPostData = StrConv(baBuffer, vbUnicode)
    End If
    Close nFile
    '--- prepare body
    sPostData = "--" & Boundary & vbCrLf & _
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""uploadfile""; filename=""" & Mid$(sFileName, InStrRev(sFileName, "\") + 1) & """" & vbCrLf & _
        "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        sPostData & vbCrLf & _
        "--" & Boundary & "--"
    '--- post
    pvGetFileAsMultipart = pvToByteArray(sPostData)
End Function

Private Function pvToByteArray(sText As String) As Byte()
    pvToByteArray = StrConv(sText, vbFromUnicode)
End Function
```

Create a new module `Processing_Code`:

```
Public Processing_Message As String
Public Macro_to_Process As String
Public Return_Value As String

Function StartProcessing(msg As String, code As String)

   Processing_Message = msg    'Set the message that is displayed
                               'in the dialog box

   Macro_to_Process = code     'Set the macro that is run after the
                               'dialog box is active

   Processing_Dialog.Show      'Show the Dialog box

   StartProcessing = Return_Value
End Function
```

Create a form `Processing_Dialog`. Set `StartUpPosition` to `2 - CenterScreen`. Add code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

   lblMessage.Caption = Processing_Message  'Change the Label
                                            'Caption

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

   Me.Repaint                                        'Refresh the UserForm
   Return_Value = Application.Run(Macro_to_Process)  'Run the macro
   Unload Me                                         'Unload the UserForm

End Sub
```

Now add a button to your Worksheet (If there is no "Developer" tab, go to "Options" -> "Customize Ribbon" -> enable checkbox "Developer") and assign macro `UploadThisFileMain`.

For the server part use this PHP test script:

```
<?php
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}

echo "POST:";
print_r($_POST);
echo "GET:";
print_r($_GET);
echo "FILES:";
print_r($_FILES);

$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
        echo "Body:$entityBody";

exit;
$base_dir = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/upload/';
if(!is_dir($base_dir))
    mkdir($base_dir, 0777);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"], $base_dir . '/' . $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]);
?>
```

Sources:

- https://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/
- http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_post-binary-data-url/
- http://fm4dd.com/programming/shell/microsoft-vbs-https-upload.htm
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/162257

Comment: This answer worked great. The methods I used were UploadThisFile, pvPostMultipart, pvGetFileAsMultipart, pvToByteArray (skipped the whole "processing dialogue" part).

Answer (score 0):

Simply posting file directly as binary body:

```
Sub UploadThisFile()
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "LOADING..."

    Dim url  As String
    url = "https://<YourServer>/index.php"

    Dim path As String
    path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

    sData = pvGetFileAsData(path)
    mimeType = "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12"

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim r
    r = pvPost(url, mimeType, sData)

    Range("A1").Select
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Upload failed: " & Err.Description
      Err.Clear
    Else
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = r
    End If
End Sub

Private Function pvPost(url, mimeType, body)
  Dim http 'As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
  Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  http.Open "POST", url, False
  http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", mimeType
  http.send body
  pvPost = http.responseText
End Function

Private Function pvGetFileAsData(sFileName As String) As Byte()
    Dim nFile           As Integer
    Dim sPostData       As String
    nFile = FreeFile
    Open sFileName For Binary Access Read As nFile
    If LOF(nFile) > 0 Then
        ReDim baBuffer(0 To LOF(nFile) - 1) As Byte
        Get nFile, , baBuffer
        pvGetFileAsData = baBuffer
    End If
    Close nFile
End Function
```

Store file on server side via PHP script:

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents('file.xlsm', $entityBody);
```